# How to expand and collapse cell correctly like accordion in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

In my app I am trying to play audio files in `UITableView`. When I tap the cell, it has to expand and play audio. Then if I tap another cell, it should act like accordion, the previous cell must collapse and audio to be stopped. But my implementation doesn't do this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AudioTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
let mp3sPaths = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType("mp3", inDirectory: nil)
var filteredAudios = [AnyObject]()
var mp3names:NSMutableArray = []
var cellTapped:Bool = true
var currentRow = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for mp3 in mp3sPaths as Array<String> {
        var mp3name = mp3.lastPathComponent
        mp3names.addObject(mp3name.stringByDeletingPathExtension)
    }
    println(mp3names)
    println(mp3sPaths)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        return self.filteredAudios.count
    } else {
        return self.mp3names.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("AudioCell") as AudioCell

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        cell.titleLabel.text = filteredAudios[indexPath.row] as? String

    } else {
        cell.titleLabel.text = mp3names[indexPath.row] as? String
    }

    cell.playIcon.text = "▶️"
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var mp3file = mp3sPaths[indexPath.row] as NSString
    var mp3URL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(mp3file)!
    var error: NSError?
    audioPlayer?.stop()
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: mp3URL, error: &error)
    audioPlayer?.play()
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? AudioCell {
        cell.playIcon.text = "◾️"
    }

    var selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? AudioCell {
        cell.playIcon.text = "▶️"
    }
    audioPlayer?.stop()

    var selectedRowIndex = indexPath
    currentRow = selectedRowIndex.row
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == currentRow {
        if cellTapped == false {
            cellTapped = true
            return 70
        } else {
            cellTapped = false
            return 40
        }
    }
    return 40
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1,1)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1,1,1)
    })
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    filteredAudios = mp3names as Array
    filteredAudios.filter{($0 as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchText)")}
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> [AnyObject]! {
    var shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = false
        println("shareAction")
    }
    shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    var doneAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Done") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = false
        println("readAction")
    }
    doneAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        tableView.editing = false
        println("deleteAction")
    }

    return [deleteAction, doneAction, shareAction]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
}
}
```

The screenshots are following:
[image: My Swift app]

Can anybody help, please?

Comment: Well you have the same delegate method function signature twice (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) I would doubt the Swift compiler would let you do that, but if it did, which one it called would be undefined (random), correct?

Comment: I haven't that twice, one is didSelect and another is didDESELECT

Comment: Ah - I missed that. I was unaware of the delegate method even. Anyway,  I had some ideas for you in my answer below

Comment: you can check this tutorial: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/ or for the swift code check: https://github.com/fawazbabu/Accordion_Menu

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've shown all the code or the current code in your example.
I have implemented the same kind of thing in swift, and I know the table animations work remarkably well if handled properly.

If the cell frame itself is larger than the height shown by the table and it has content, you need to hide the overhanging subviews in the cell's contentContview when you collapse the cell via heightForRowAtIndexPath, or the visible subview overhanging cell frame will show through the other cells in the table after the cell is collapsed.   That may be what's happening in your case but it's hard to tell for sure from your write-up.

But setting the alpha directly all at once looks tacky.  You should animate the alpha property of the cell.contentView subviews that need to hide when the cell shrinks, and when the cell expands, using UIView.animateWithDuration()  You want them to fade out as the row contracts and fade in as it expands.

Comment: I added full code of viewController file. Please, can you read it and suggest your solution?

Comment: I am confused by the diagrams and the what vs. expected performance so I'm not clear still exactly what's going wrong where, or what you want to happen.  Anyway, I can't really write or design your app for you or take the time to study it to come up to speed on everything you're doing.

Comment: ok, you don't have to write code of app, of course) All I need is to realize the accordion table view such as this: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u34Fw9biD3k&feature=youtu.be](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u34Fw9biD3k&feature=youtu.be). I think the code that I wrote is enough to understand and to suggest correction

Comment: If I don't need to write code or an app then what I posted should be enough for you to figure out what you need to do.  You can use a rotation affine transform to rotate the arrow button 90º (e.g. π/2) and back to 0º with an animation in parallel with the fade in and fade out of the oversized part of the cell contents to achieve the effect. It works.  The research and coding part you'll have to figure out. I've already put more time than I can spare into this answer and as you can see others aren't jumping on board to help.